# How to add/link Facebook Messenger Maps to the bot button?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

Struggling to add/link Facebook Messenger maps to the bot button. Want to get user's location, users can pinpoint and search the location. Pictures are attached to clarify what I am struggling with and trying to achieve.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrF7c.jpg **[Button "Send Location"][1]**
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DahRC.jpg **[When user clicks on the button "Send Location", it should brings up the maps(facebook-messenger-maps), where user can pinpoint or search the location][2]**

Comment: The location button is a quick replies in messenger platform. Here is the developer guideline-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies#locations

Comment: @ssakash Thanks alot. Can you guide me how to set/add "Send location"(quick reply button). I am newbie, so I find it hard.

Answer (score 0):

These are the quick Replies in messenger platform.

```
QuickReply quickreply = new QuickReply("Title","payload");
Message message = new Message("any string");
message.addQuickReply();
message.setMetadata("metadata payload"); // optional metadata
SendMessage(recipient,message)
```

This is the syntax of declaring and sending quick reply to messenger.
Happy Coding:-)